# Incompatible types error when calling method from main

Tags: java, methods

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
import static java.lang.Double.*;
import static java.lang.Integer.*;

public class MetodeØve  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        skrivTegn("hei",15);
    }

    private static void skrivTegn (char t, int antall) {
        for (int i =1;  i<=antall; i++)
            out.print(t);   
        }
    }
}
```

---

I'm getting "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char" when compiling, and I don't understand what exactly I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions?

Comment: `"hei"` is not a `char`, it's a `String`. That is why you have the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static void skrivTegn (char t, int antall) {
```

The first argument to this method is a char.  When you call it:

```
skrivTegn("hei",15);
```

you're passing the first argument as a String.  If you change the method to be:

```
private static void skrivTegn (String t, int antall) {
```

it will likely be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Char is just one character. Strings contain multiple characters.

Read about char here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

```
private static void skrivTegn (String t, int antall) {
..
}
```

Change the parameter to String and then you can use the function charAt() to get the character from a string at a specific position.

Answer (score 0):

char only contains a single character!
ex: `skrivTegn('a',15)`